# Removing file name and swapping forward slashes for dashes with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Im in the middle of moving my blog from a dynamic site to a static site. As a part of not breaking too many links I'm trying to learn mod_rewrite but getting no where with the following RewriteRule:

My old url

```
/blog/index.cfm/2012/10/9/My-blog-post
```

My new url

```
/blog/2012-10-09-My-blog-post.html
```

So far I have the following in my vhosts.conf file but its not working

```
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)(/blog/index.cfm/)([0-9]+)(/)([0-9]+)(/)([0-9]+)(/)([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) $1/blog/$3-$5-$7.html
```

Any help/pointers would be great

Answer (score 0):

First, you only need to bracket (i.e. capture) things you will be using on the RHS of your rule.  But the problem appears to be that you are only copying the year, month and day to the RHS, but not the `My-blog-post`.  Try this:

```
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)/blog/index.cfm/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) $1/blog/$2-$3-$4-$5.html
```

Comment: I've quickly updated the rule but it hasn't worked. Im gonna spend some more time on it tonight and get the mod_rewrite logging and seeing if I have missed something else.

My current vhost file has the following now in it (for reference)

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)/blog/index.cfm/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) $1/blog/$2-$3-$4-$5.html